# Getting date and time from Datepicker and timepicker add-on and Storing into DateTime column in DB without using string

Tags: c#, datetime, datepicker

I am getting date and time from a combination of datepicker and timepicker add-on and want to store this date and time i.e. "26-11-2013 23:50" or "26-11-2013 11:50 PM" into SQL Server 2005 DateTime column. later on I want to use the dates to compare them like date1 > date2 etc.For this my .aspx is as follow:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#MainContent_txtDate").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, controlType: 'select',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
            stepMinute: 15
        });
    });

</script>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Add Journey</legend>
    <h2>Add Journey</h2>

    <ol>
        <li>
            <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="txtDate" runat="server">Date</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </li>
</ol>
</fieldset>
</asp:Content>
```

in .aspx.cs I am doing

```
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "d", provider);
        Mytable.Column=date;
```

it gives FormatException. I tried `DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd-mm-yy hh:mm tt", provider);` but same result.

I do not want to use string for whole this purpose (but txtDate.Text gives string)

Comment: Could you give an example of the value of `txtDate.Text`?

Comment: ``"26-11-2013 23:50"`` and ``"26-11-2013 11:50 PM"`` are both examples of ``txtDate.Text``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for "26-11-2013 23:50":

```
   CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
        DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, format, provider);
        Mytable.Column=date;
```

The hours should be `HH`, this represent a 24-hourly clock. `hh` is when you use AM/PM.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/K3F4O3)

Comment: Same ``FormatException`` ``String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.``

Comment: @Rahman If you debug, just make sure your `txtDate.Text` is passed in the correct format from the front-end. If it truly is in this format `26-11-2013 23:50`, then the proposed code shouldn't go wrong.

Comment: I don't know how to add image, I wanted to show you value of ``txtDate.Text;`` while debugging

Comment: @Rahman You can't because you don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Yup, however I wanted to show that ``txtDate.Text;`` gives this format ``"26-11-2013 23:50"``. I am also storing its value in a string to see its value, it seems fine

Answer (score 0):

You have two different formats - one that is 24 hours and one that is with an AM/PM designator.

You need to try and parse with both - `ParseExact` has an overload that takes an array of format strings, which is a suitable overload in this case:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, 
                       new string[] {"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt"}, 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Now, the format string you have used - `dd-mm-yy hh:mm tt` is using `mm` incorrectly for months - it should be `MM` for months, and `mm` for minutes.

Comment: ``DateTimeStyles.?`` is it typo or what?

Comment: same ``FormatException`` still there. By the way at a time I am using only one of these formats (I have the flexibility of using any of them) ``"26-11-2013 23:50"`` or ``"26-11-2013 11:50 PM"``

Comment: @Rahman - What is the value of `txtDate.Text` then? It can't be either of those if you are getting a format exception.

Comment: @Rahman - no, it isn't. Or rather, if it is, you are either not using those format strings or not using `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41955/discussion-between-rahman-and-oded)